# Programmatically provide data property for a marker on a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I use Leaflet for mapping solution for a proof of concept work, 
and currently stuck for the last couple days at the following issue:

I am adding a marker by clicking on Leaflet map, and by using following leaflet function:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(e.layer.toGeoJSON()));
```

I get this GeoJSON string result:

> {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[115.1806640625,-2.7235830833483856]}}

What I need is the following GeoJSON string:

> {"type":"Feature","properties":{"namo":"Babakansumedang"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[115.1806640625,-2.7235830833483856]}}

The question: How can I programmatically using Leaflet function/Javascript or other possible way,
 inserting "namo":"Babakansumedang" into GeoJSON "properties"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass that alert to variable and then create a new key value pair for each feature.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(e.layer.toGeoJSON()),
    features = json.features;

features.forEach(feat) {
  json.feat.properties["namo"] = "Babakansumedang";
}
```